# Netbeans 10 --> Tools --> available plugins --> JAVA EE Base missing?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've installed Apache Netbeans 10 and it does not have JAVA WEB option while creating new project. I checked available plugins but **JAVA EE Base** option is missing.

[image: Available Plugins Image]